# Volatile variables and standard library functions

Tags: parameter-passing, volatile

I am using the "volatile" for my array now. But I have a problem with some standard library functions. I am using a C-compiler.

If I am doing so:

```
...
static volatile uint8_t inPrevStates[EV_INPUTS_QUANTITY];
...

void foo(void)
{
    ...
    memset(inPrevStates, 0x01, sizeof(inPrevStates));
    ...
}
```

I am getting this:

> note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'volatile uint8_t *'

If I am doing so:

```
void foo(void)
{
    ...
    memset((void*) inPrevStates, 0x01, sizeof(inPrevStates));
    ...
}
```

I am getting this:

> warning: cast discards '**attribute**((noreturn))' qualifier from
>   pointer target type [-Wcast-qual]|

What should I do?